# How to understand if train/validation/test sets are statistically similar for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, neural-networks

In machine learning, I train data on e.g. a training set, and use a validation/test set to test if my model has not only learned the training set but has generalised/understands the general relationships well, and is not merely overfitting. The underlying assumption is that validation and test sets are from the same underlying distribution as the training data and are statistically essentially the same. I.e. the only thing we're not learning is noise.

In timeseries, though, this is not always the case. Data is non-stationary, we cannot select from X1,...,XN examples M training examples and J test examples (N=M+J), at random, due to possible correlations in the data. We may have to do something like walk-forward validation: https://machinelearningmastery.com/backtest-machine-learning-models-time-series-forecasting/

What this means is data from 2010-2018 could be used for training, data after it could be val/test. If there was a freak event in 2019 that simply didn't occur in 2010-18 a perfectly generalising model would have a good train MSE (say) and still not be able to give a good test MSE.

How do we know for timeseries data if two samples are fundamentally statistically similar such that it is 'only noise' that is a difference? So that any difference in train to test MSE is due to a model that doesn't generalise well, and not that these two datasets are fundamentally somewhat different. I believe Kullback-Leibler divergence may offer something like this, but I don't know how to understand what "big" is in KLD (e.g. is 0.1 good for two certain dists, 2.3 bad for others).

How do I know when a 'non-perfect' score (MSE, R2 etc.) is due to 1) a model not being as good as it could be, and when it is due to 2) my model is generalising perfectly from 10-18 to 19, but that this non-perfect score is inherently due to e.g. the distributions being slightly different?